# Class not found in class path exception while running my git test through run.bat file in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, testing, jenkins, github, selenium-webdriver

I am learning to execute the eclipse automation code through Git with Jenkins. While running the bat script manually, it is running without any issue. However, while running it through Git, it is throwing class not found in Classpath exception.

**Error log**

```
Building in workspace C:\Users\DELL\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsGitTest
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Satish152/GitTest.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Satish152/GitTest.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/Satish152/GitTest.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 2e7f307474859cf6d5a4323cf210fbdd8a63200b (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 2e7f307474859cf6d5a4323cf210fbdd8a63200b
Commit message: "changes made in class name"
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk fd6a75f2c57c49a45971fe35ec8b047910849b16 # timeout=10
[JenkinsGitTest] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins1401414693910390241.bat

C:\Users\DELL\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsGitTest>run.bat

C:\Users\DELL\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsGitTest>set classpath=H:\workspace\GitHubTest\bin;H:\workspace\GitHubTest\lib\*; 

C:\Users\DELL\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsGitTest>java -cp bin;lib\* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml 
[TestNG] [ERROR] 
Cannot find class in classpath: gitTest.DemoGitTest
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm adding Jenkins project configuration screenshot below:

[image: Git project configuration in [![Git project configuration in jenkins1]Jenkins][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNTC4.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNTC4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be you're overwriting the `classpath` and it missing semicolon `;`, try this

```
set classpath=H:\workspace\GitHubTest\bin;H:\workspace\GitHubTest\lib\*; 
java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

or remove `set classpath` and do

```
java -cp bin/*;lib/*; org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Comment: thank you for the comment.. Definitely will try this.. Present I'm not able to do but tomorrow my first thing is to try this.